# No visible files in DIR (site/default/files) throught the IMCE

Tags: files

I have a problem with IMCE manager:

1. I upload my files throught CONTENT -> FILES, all files are visible there (sites/default/files).
2. I check (Home » Administration » Configuration » Media » IMCE) for sites/default/files path and permissions. It's all OK.
3. But when I use IMCE "Add Link" button to link an uploaded file, and choose to pick it up from server... I see nothing (except 0 files using 0 bytes of unlimited quota) in file browser. Navigation tab also shows: /sites/default/files

Files folder has 0777.
Uploaded files can be also opened by ULR.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> Filefield sources applies a filter to the file list. It won't list files that can not be used in file field.

https://drupal.org/node/1099994

If you are using File Field sources that's your problem.